# wrong output by vs2017 but mingw works

Tags: c++, file, gcc, mingw, visual-studio-2017

I wrote a simple function to load a char * buffer from a file but when compiled through vs2017 it add rubbish at the end of the buffer but mingw compiled exe gives correct output 
the function looks like something

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

char * loadfromfile(const char * _Filename)
{
    char * buffer;
    FILE * file = fopen(_Filename, "r");
    if (!file)
        return nullptr;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    auto _length = ftell(file);
    buffer = new char[_length + 1];
    rewind(file);
    printf("characters read(loadformfile()) :%i\n",fread(buffer, sizeof(char), _length, file));
    buffer[_length] = '\0';
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}

int main() {
    char * str = loadfromfile("D:\\shutdown.bat");
    printf("%s\n", (str) ? str : "failed to load");
    delete[] str;
    return 0;
}
```

VS2017 output:

```
characters read(loadformfile()) :86
@echo off
Set minutes=30
set /a seconds=%minutes%*60
TIMEOUT /T %seconds%
shutdown /s
\inst
```

g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 7.1.0 output:

```
characters read(loadformfile()) :zu
@echo off
Set minutes=30
set /a seconds=%minutes%*60
TIMEOUT /T %seconds%
shutdown /s
```

file is:

```
@echo off
Set minutes=30
set /a seconds=%minutes%*60
TIMEOUT /T %seconds%
shutdown /s
```

**EDIT:**

```
A working solution 
char * loadfromfile(const char * _Filename)
{
    char * buffer;
    FILE * file = fopen(_Filename, "r");
    if (!file)
        return nullptr;
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    auto _length = ftell(file);
    buffer = new char[_length + 1];
    rewind(file);
    buffer[fread(buffer, sizeof(char), _length, file)] = '\0';
    fclose(file);
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: There is a note here saying `ftell` with files open in text mode reports incorrect position: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx

Comment: maybe that is right, added a working solution

Comment: is this only vs's ftell which reports wrong, i mean gcc's version worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't portably use `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file.

Per [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), footnote 268, p 301:

> Setting  the  file  position  indicator  to  end-of-file,  as  with
>   `fseek(file,  0,  SEEK_END)`,  has undefined behavior for a binary
>   stream ...

and

> **7.21.9.2  The `fseek` function**
>
> ... A binary stream need not meaningfully support `fseek` calls with a
>   `whence` value of `SEEK_END`.

So you can't reliably use `fseek()` to get to the end of a binary file.  In fact, doing so is *specifically* stated by the C Standard to be undefined behavior.

OK, so you can use `fseek()` to get to the end of a file opened in *text* mode, but

> **7.21.9.4  The `ftell` function**
>
> ...
>
> For a text stream, its file position indicator contains unspecified
>   information, usable by the `fseek` function for returning the file
>   position indicator for the stream  to  its  position  at  the  time 
>   of  the `ftell` call;  the  difference  between  two  such return
>   values is not necessarily a meaningful measure of the number of
>   characters written or read.

On a text file, `ftell()` doesn't return a value useful in getting the file size.

In short, using `fseek()`/`ftell()` to get the size of a file is fundamentally broken.  The fact that it works *sometimes* is just an implementation detail.

Comment: Is it possible that it will report less sometime or it is too implement detail? Because then the solution i am using will break.

Comment: @bluedragon C has no standardized concept of a "file", so any solution will have to be platform-specific.  For Windows, offhand I think `GetFileSize( fileno( file ) );` should work, although `GetFileSizeEx()` is probably better, while `struct stat  sb; fstat( fileno( file ) &sb );` would work on POSIX systems.  On Windows and POSIX systems, `fseek()`/`ftell()` on *binary* streams does work, but the size is limited to a signed `long` value, or 2 GB on Windows.  You can use `ftello()` to get an `off_t` value, which should be 64 bits for 64-bit all architectures.

Comment: will a loop finding EOF will work for correct ftell()